# Why does adding IdentityDbContext into DbContext give me an error?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, identity

In my ASP.NET Core 3.1 application, I started using identity for authentication.  I realised that I had two classes `ApplebyContext` (my database context) and `ApplicationDbContext` (inherits `IdentityDbContext`).  I don't want to separate files for this and, after some searching, I saw that it's common to just merge the two together.

With that in mind, I attempted to do this but I'm receiving errors.  I had my 'DBContext' code which looked like this:

```
using Appleby.Data;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Appleby.Repo
{
    public class ApplebyContext : DbContext
    {
        public ApplebyContext(DbContextOptions<ApplebyContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
        public DbSet<Products> Products { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }
    }
}
```

I also had my `ApplicationDbContext` (which I set up in a different project whilst implementing identity), which looks like this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using WebApplication1.Models;

namespace WebApplication1.Data
{
    public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
    }

}
```

From what I saw, all I would need to do is state that my `ApplebyContext` would inherit `IdentityDbContext`, so I merged the code like so:

```
using Appleby.Data;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

namespace Appleby.Repo
{
    public class ApplebyContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplebyContext(DbContextOptions<ApplebyContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }
        public DbSet<Products> Products { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        }
    }
}
```

However, I get an error on `options` in `public ApplebyContext(DbContextOptions<ApplebyContext> options) : base(options)` of:

> The type 'Appleby.Repo.ApplebyContext' cannot be used as type
>   parameter 'TContext' in the generic type or method
>   'DbContextOptions'. There is no implicit reference
>   conversion from 'Appleby.Repo.ApplebyContext' to
>   'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext'.

Can anyone assist? Have I perhaps missed a reference or indeed, set this up incorrectly?

Comment: Have you perhaps mixed versions of Entity Framework here? Make sure you are only referencing a single version of the library.

Comment: @DavidG It's possible, however, removing one or the other causes additional errors.  For example, if I remove `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework;` I can't use `IdentityDbContext`.  If I remove `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;` I can't use `dbContextOptions` or `DbSet`

Comment: No, I meant multiple versions of the same DLLs. What you are doing here is perfectly valid code, I'm not sure why it is giving you an error message.

Comment: Frankly, I think you were on the right track with separate contexts. Separation of concerns.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkcore` not `Asp.Identity.EntityFrameworkcore`.